# Dependency error while trying to integrate Google Sign in on my app

Tags: android

I am following this guide to integrate Google sign in to my app
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Here is my app level **build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

}
```

On adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'` I get error on `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

The error is

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

I looked into the library folder and there are two libraries with a different version number. See the picture below

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you need to add those libraries too as dependencies with the versions matching your appCompat version library.

Comment: You can check the hint that you will be getting on hover with your mouse cursor on that error line. Change the version as suggested in the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below to you app level gradle in the end

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                        details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should also add some details in your answer, what exactly this method do and why we use it instead of updating our dependencies ?

Comment: sure. I will. Stackoverflow asking me to wait for sometime before they allow me to accept a correct answer. So I'll need to wait for few more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the examples to your gradle, and give them the latest version also, 27.1.1.

Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

E.g.

mplementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'